# for sql server, I want to select all of the records that has changed

Tags: sql-server

for example, my table has a record for each date, and each date's record could be same as the previous date record, could be different. my case is from date 1 to date 3, all of the record are same, and then date 4, the record is changed, date 5 the record is changed too, but it changed back to same as date 3. Now I want to a way to query the table and get the records of date 1, date 4 and date 5. Any idea, how to do it? Thanks

Comment: Does your table have a column which stores the datetime of when the date you're talking about changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the issue above, is that a) you take daily logs of all rows, and b) you want to report on any row that is different from the previous day's.

SQL Server has a great function for dealing with differences across a large number of columns - [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). It also has the advantage of treating NULLs as distinct values - so a change from something to NULL, or vice versa, counts as a change. This is not true for most equality/inequality checks.

Here is a version where I create a daily snapshot of some fields from a 'users' table.

The SELECT query finds all rows from the log, except where the previous entry in the log is the same.

```
CREATE TABLE #UserLog (LogDate date, UserID int, UserName nvarchar(100), UserEmail nvarchar(100), LastLogonDate datetime, PRIMARY KEY (LogDate, UserID));

INSERT INTO #UserLog (LogDate, UserID, UserName, UserEmail, LastLogonDate) VALUES
('20201011',  1,  'Bob',  NULL,          '20201009 15:38'),
('20201012',  1,  'Bob',  NULL,          '20201009 15:38'),
('20201013',  1,  'Bob',  'Bob@gm.com',  '20201012 09:15'),
('20201014',  1,  'Bob',  'Bob@gm.com',  '20201013 19:02'),
('20201015',  1,  'Bob',  'Bob@gm.com',  '20201013 19:02'),
('20201017',  1,  'Bob',  'Bob@gm.com',  '20201013 19:02'),
('20201013',  2,  'Pat',  'Pat@hm.com',   NULL),
('20201014',  2,  'Pat',  'Pat@hm.com',   NULL),
('20201015',  2,  'Pat',  'Pat@hm.com',  '20201014 20:55'),
('20201017',  2,  'Pat',  'Pat@hm.com',  '20201016 13:22');

SELECT  LogDate, UserID, UserName, UserEmail, LastLogonDate
  FROM  #UserLog
EXCEPT
SELECT  LEAD(LogDate) OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY LogDate), UserID, UserName, UserEmail, LastLogonDate
  FROM  #UserLog
ORDER BY UserID, LogDate;
```

In the 'EXCEPT' segment, it basically gets the data for each given row, then changes the date to the next date in sequence for that user e.g., it turns

```
('20201012',  1,  'Bob',  NULL,          '20201009 15:38'),
```

into

```
('20201013',  1,  'Bob',  NULL,          '20201009 15:38'),
```

As this is not the same as the *actual* row for Bob on the 13th, the row in the top part of the statement shows.

My initial test run of this simply had a DATEADD(day, 1, Logdate) in the EXCEPT portion, and that would show all rows that were different from yesterday's. However, the updated version above allows for breaks in the sequence (e.g., in the above, the logging failed on the 16th).

Here's a [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d49a38f4ad975e70663a05fd25e44444) with the code above.

---

UPDATE - data posted in comment in another answer.

Here's a version with that data.

```
CREATE TABLE #tLog (LogDate date, v_1 int, v_2 varchar(100), v_3 int, v_4 varchar(10), v_5 int, v_6 varchar(10));
INSERT INTO #tLog (Logdate, v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6) VALUES
('20200101',  100,  'test_1',  0,    '123',   120,  'JJ'), 
('20200102',  100,  'test_1',  0,    '123',   120,  'JJ'), 
('20200103',  100,  'test_1',  0,    '123',   120,  'JJ'), 
('20200104',  101,  'test_1',  1,    '123',   120,  'JJ'), 
('20200105',  100,  'test_1',  0,    '123',   120,  'JJ'), 
('20200106',  101,  'test_1',  1,    '12345', 120,  'JJ'), 
('20200107',  101,  'test_1',  1,    '12345', 120,  'JJ'), 
('20200108',  101,  'test_2',  2,    '12345', 200,  'JJ'), 
('20200109',  101,  'test_1',  1,    '12345', 120,  'TT'), 
('20200110',  100,  'test_1',  0,    '123',   120,  'JJ');

SELECT  LogDate, v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6
  FROM  #tLog
EXCEPT
SELECT  LEAD(LogDate) OVER (ORDER BY LogDate), v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4, v_5, v_6
  FROM  #tLog
ORDER BY LogDate;
```

And here's a copy of the results of the above. Note that only on the 2nd, 3rd and 7th did the data not change from the previous day.

```
LogDate     v_1  v_2     v_3 v_4    v_5  v_6
--------------- ----------------------------
2020-01-01  100  test_1  0   123    120  JJ
2020-01-04  101  test_1  1   123    120  JJ
2020-01-05  100  test_1  0   123    120  JJ
2020-01-06  101  test_1  1   12345  120  JJ
2020-01-08  101  test_2  2   12345  200  JJ
2020-01-09  101  test_1  1   12345  120  TT
2020-01-10  100  test_1  0   123    120  JJ
```

Note that I have removed the 'PARTITION BY' in the LEAD as there are no real partitions - it's just one row after the next. However there's a distinct chance you may need this when it comes to actual data.

Here's a [DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=885493eb4669607f8970edbe3ba5eaa1) with both the original and this cut-down one with the OP's data.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I want.